# Are adverbial modifiers in decline?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbials, intensifying-adverbs

Words such as *rather* and *quite* are characteristically used in English to modify meaning,

According to Paul Baker in Lancaster University:

> complex and understated forms of speech are in decline.
>
> [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/science/shortcuts/2017/nov/13/british-art-understatement-decline-american-english)
>
> He has said that he is rather fond of such “*gradable adverbs*”, stating that:
>
> "Some words are starting to be drastically eroded from English – especially a grammatical class called “*gradable adverbs*” which consists of boosters (that emphasis another word or phrase, otherwise known as intensifying adverbs) like *frightfully* & *awfully* and downtoners (that reduce the force of another word or phrase) like *quite* and *rather*."
>
> [Guardian](https://theconversation.com/the-americanisation-of-the-english-language-a-frightfully-subtle-affair-86348)

On the other hand, Google ngram shows little ground for this concern in British English, either for the boosters or the downtoners. Here are the downtoners *rather* and *quite*:

[image]

And here are the boosters I mentioned:

[image]

My question to you is: what is your own experience of the claimed change in our language? And with which source does it agree – Professor Baker or ngram?

Comment: The decline of degree adverbs: https://commachameleon.co.uk/blog/the-decline-of-degree-adverbs/ - The decline of the gradable adverb: 'quite', 'rather' and 'fairly' are becoming a relic of the past. https://www.telegraph.co.uk/education/2017/11/11/decline-gradable-adverb-quite-rather-fairly-becoming-relic-past/

Comment: @user66974 useful material, and a fuller account than the Guardian version. Thank you.

Comment: @Anton Rather has uses other than as an adverb. *I would rather play than work.* So it’s not quite a fair comparison.